# What Javascript type conversions are happening here?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I found a bug in a script that was written, and I'm having troubles figuring out exactly what is causing the issues. Specifically:

```
"49px" < 50 === false
```

There's two different conversions I can think of here:

```
49 < 50 === true
"49px" < "50" === true
"49" < 50 === true // just for the hell of it
```

I fixed it with:

```
parseInt("49px") < 50 === true
```

So why does this evaluate to false? What exactly is happening here?

Comment: Check out the [Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5)...

Comment: Fix is inadequate. Number("49px") happens, parseInt/Float are behaving differently

Comment: y u no specifiy a radix in your parse int?! https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt do it now while it's not too late!

Comment: @user422039: Look at the documentation for `parseInt`, it is working properly and as expected. `Number("49px")` does not call `parseInt`, it interprets the string as an exact number.

Comment: reread my comment, original variant code does not use any of parseXXX function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If one operand is a number and another operand is a string, then [the string is converted to a number](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1) and then the comparison is made.

If the string cannot be converted to a number, it gets converted to `NaN`, and the comparison always returns `false`.

Answer (score 3):

When javascript is asked to compare a number with something else, it tries to convert that "something else" to a number.  In this case, `"49px"` evaluates to `NaN` so `NaN < 50` is `false`.

Comment: darn, just a few minutes too late!